# What would cause a computer to not boot unless "Global C-state control" is disabled?

Tags: windows-10, boot, freeze, bsod, amd-ryzen

I've been having boot issues all day where the computer would freeze up while booting Windows or a Debian live usb, booted memtest86 just fine though. Windows would sometimes throw a clock_watchdog_timeout BSOD as well. Reset the BIOS, reseated the GPU, RAM, and even the CPU. Took the drives down to just what was needed to boot and even did single/dual RAM stick boot tests cycling through the sticks to see if maybe it was that.
It only booted when I disabled the "Global C-state Control" option in the BIOS. I am quite confused at this and wondered if anyone had any explanation.

- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19044) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor
- Memory: 65536MB RAM w/o XMP/DOCP enabled
- Motherboard: ASUS Crosshair VIII Hero
- BIOS ver: 4501

Comment: "Global C-state Control" lets the BIOS turn off partly the CPU to conserve power. Is your BIOS the [latest version](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-crosshair/rog-crosshair-viii-hero-model/helpdesk_bios/)?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, the BIOS is the latest version, and I am aware of what C-states are, I'm just confused as to why an OS would refuse to boot with the C-state control enabled.

Comment: No real idea. Perhaps a BIOS implementation bug.